# How to fetch Workflow ID from Workflow Instance ID in Dynamics 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-365

This is regarding CodeActivities in Microsoft CRM Workflows in Dynamics CRM 365. I need to fetch notes related to a workflow in my code activity. For that I need workflow Id of that workflow in my code activity. But there is only Workflow Instance Id in code activity context and not the Workflow Id. How can I get workflow Id form workflow Instance Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot get this directly.

Workaround is to setup an Input Parameter & send the Workflow name or even Workflow Id as a configuration item in designer. Read this Input param in codeactivity & retrieve the annotations associated with it.

This way, even if you have multiple workflows calling/executing the same codeactivity will work nicely.

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried this. I am looking for a way to do it without passing parameter

Comment: @user3085988 this might be the only way, as secured/unsecured config is not available for WF, also Id cannot be retrieved from DB as this transaction is not yet committed. Unless you decide to hardcode the name/Id in code..

Comment: Yes, you are right about retrieving Id from DB. So passing information about the workflow as parameter looks like the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to get id of workflow using C#:

```
IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

//Retrieve processid of current workflow instance
Entity asyncOperation = service.Retrieve("asyncoperation", 
    context.OperationId, new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ColumnSet("workflowactivationid"));

var workflowid = asyncOperation.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("workflowactivationid").Id;
```

After that you can use it to fetch notes.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you reply. I tried this method but I am getting the error "asyncoperation with this id does not exist". I have tried it with both real time and background workflow mode.